# Problem showing an image in a laravel website

Tags: laravel

I save images in a controller with the `$imagePath = "/upload/images/{$adver}` address. Then these images are saved in a public folder in the root folder, but when I move these images file into the C-Panel I can't see them.

The address of an image is saved in `advertise table` and  the images are saved in the public folder. I use `src="advertise.image1"` to show an image.

The images are in a database and I get the route to database to show them on the website.

[image]

Comment: You have to use asset with image

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the public_path helper function?

```
$imagePath = public_path("/upload/images/{$adver}");
```

You may have issues with your public path if you're saying they're not working on the remote location. Is your remote public path set as `public_html` rather than public?

Comment: This does not look like an answer - please use comments to ask questions or request clarification.

Comment: Yes, I do. @Friendly Code